# HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync does not delete auth cookie

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-1.0

According to ASP.NET Core [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie) the method  `HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync()` must delete the authentication cookie as well.

> **Signing out**
>
> To sign out the current user, and *delete their cookie* (italics mine - A.C.) call the following inside your controller
>
> `await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance");`

But it does not! Everything else seems okay, esp. auth scheme, because user gets signed-in  correctly and the cookie .AspNetCore. is created.

Any ideas why cookie remains after the user's sing-out?

Comment: is this still relevant today ?

Comment: Docs slightly changed - instead of "MyCookieMiddlewareInstance" they say CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, which is obviously not the same. However, if the code deletes the cookie, is something that you check easily yourself. After all, this is called in  AccountController (LogOff methodprovided you enabled authentication when scaffolding your app.

Answer (score 37):

You didn't post enough code to tell, but I suspect after you call `SignOutAsync` you have some type of redirect (for example, `RedirectToAction`) which overwrites the redirect to the OIDC endsession URL that `SignOutAsync` tries to issue.

(The same explanation for the redirect overwrite problem is given [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/313#issuecomment-120668602) by Microsoft's HaoK.)

Edit: If my speculation above is correct, the solution is to send a redirect URL in an `AuthenticationProperties` object with the final `SignOutAsync`:

```cs
// in some controller/handler, notice the "bare" Task return value
public async Task LogoutAction()
{
    // SomeOtherPage is where we redirect to after signout
    await MyCustomSignOut("/SomeOtherPage");
}

// probably in some utility service
public async Task MyCustomSignOut(string redirectUri)
{
    // inject the HttpContextAccessor to get "context"
    await context.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
    var prop = new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        RedirectUri = redirectUri
    };
    // after signout this will redirect to your provided target
    await context.SignOutAsync("oidc", prop);
}
```

Comment: perfect solution.

Comment: I'm very frustrated by the design of the `SignOutAsync` / `ChallengeAsync` extension-methods because there's absolutely no immediate indication that shows consumers should not be setting their own `IActionResult` afterwards. Why can't `SignOutAsync` return its own `IActionResult`? That way it's obvious to consumers that they should pass the response along.

Comment: @Dai `SignOutAsync` is redirecting the client to the OIDC signout endpoint, so it can't return an arbitrary `IActionResult`, it has to be an HTTP redirect status for the OIDC flow to work properly. I do wish all of this stuff was documented better, though. MS API docs are largely automated these days and they leave a lot to be desired.

Comment: @McGuireV10 is right, it redirects correctly without specifying an RedirectUri. The big point in this response is that there are two calls of SignOutAsync; Once I have called await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) it deleted the cookie.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, it redirects to `/SomeOtherPage` but the cookie is still there

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue recently. In my case, the browser had created multiple cookies. One with a name like ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery" and another one with a custom name that I had set for my cookie in startup.cs.

What solved the error for me was the first part of [JTvermose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43089132/2908576) with some changes. I added the code below to my logout method. Worked like a charm.

```
    if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Count> 0) 
        {
            var siteCookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Where(c => c.Key.Contains(".AspNetCore.") || c.Key.Contains("Microsoft.Authentication"));
            foreach (var cookie in siteCookies)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
            }
        }

                await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        HttpContext.Session.Clear();
        return RedirectToPage("/Index");
```

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same problem.
SignOutAsync does not work as should .

I found this:

```
Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.<nameofcookie>");
```

Comment: Where? In source code or somewhere else (blog, answer, etc.)? And magic strings are really nasty, despite the shorter code.

Comment: @AlexanderChristov what's a magic string?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner Hardcoded strings are considered "magic" strings. Instead you can use constants, resources, etc. to get rid of them since you may easily misspell one, or just forget to change it once needed.

Answer (score 3):

Solved the issue with this first line.

```cs
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
// await _SignInManager.SignOutAsync();
// HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Cookies");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code that deletes the cookie (If nothing else helps, use brute force):

```
await this.HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync(<AuthenticationScheme>);

// ...

var cookie = this.Request.Cookies[<CookieName>];
if (cookie != null)
{
    var options = new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) };
    this.Response.Cookies.Append(cookieName, cookie, options);
}
```

Bad, bad, bad! Seems like a very ugly patch! But works... :(

Any ***other*** solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with deleting my site cookies with the following snippet placed in my Logout() method in the controller. I found that multiple cookies would be created by my site.

```
// Delete the authentication cookie(s) we created when user signed in
            if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies[".MyCookie"] != null)
            {
                var siteCookies = HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Where(c => c.Key.StartsWith(".MyCookie"));
                foreach (var cookie in siteCookies)
                {
                    Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
                }
            }
```

And in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login/"),
                AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Home/Index/"),
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                CookieName = ".MyCookie"
            });
```

Notice that I do not use `await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("MyCookieMiddlewareInstance");` since I am using OpenIdConnect with Google.

Comment: I guess only a single cookie (the auth one) must be deleted. Deleting all cookies placed by your site seems like a very brute force and maybe undesirable, despite it may work. And deleting a single cookie seems like a solution already suggested by Castro JR, do you see a difference?
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, this line of code works -

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Identity.Application");
```

Comment: Correct. You can also use 
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your case was to use ASP **NET Core Identity authentication** stuff like in my case

so, instead of using *HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync()* or *HttpContext.SignOutAsync()* you can try to use API from ASP NET Identity:

**SignInManager.SignOutAsync()**

API from HttpContext didn't clear cookies with names starting with ".AspNetCore."

(to use SignInManager you need to bring in SignInMbanager by asp net core's DI)

Comment: I am using signInManager.SignOutAsync() and then - sign in different user using signInManager.SignInAsync(identityUser, true). Everything seems to look ok, but in fact CurrentUser does not change! And when I am back to my Angular app and reload the page - i keep seeing the previous logged user. What I need to do is to sign in a different user without logging off (switching to different user is supposed to work via dropdown in Angular UI and calling app service method)

Answer (score 1):

In my case McGuireV10's answer didn't work as `await context.SignOutAsync("oidc", prop);` did not redirect to my given redirectUri.

I solved it by adding `HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectUri);` after the SignOutAsync call.

Answer (score 1):

This one will do the job like a charm.

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
HttpContext.Session.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code

```
await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            Response.Cookies.Delete("CookieName");         
            return RedirectToAction("login", "Account");
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is a way to make this `if(HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)`
to result to  `false` then do you can do this: `HttpContext.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>()));`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).