# How to log out External Authentication Schemes like Facebook in ASP .NET MVC Core?

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, asp.net-core, facebook-login

I have a ASP .NET MVC Core app and I am implementing a very simple login page where I use IdentityUser to let the user login with Username, Email and Password. I also am using External Authentication Providers such as Facebook as well. Normal login/logout is working as it should. And when it comes to facebook, the login works fine:

```
 public IActionResult FacebookLogin()
    {
        AuthenticationProperties authProps = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = Url.Action("Index", "Home")
        };

        return Challenge(authProps, "Facebook");
    }
```

But I have problem to logout when I am logged in using Facebook. Here is my logout code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signinManager.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

No matter what I do, I cant logout when I'm logged in using Facebook
Any Help appreciated.
It is worth noting that I have a partial view as follows:

[image]

Whenever I login with facebook it the IsAuthenticated flag is set to true, but when I log out it is never set to false

Comment: So, do you get an error when you attempt to log out? Do you get anything to go on?

Comment: @R.Richards No I don't get any errors. I have a partial view where I use the **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated** to choose between Logout or Login button. When I try to logout of Facebook it is never set to false.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122053/httpcontext-authentication-signoutasync-does-not-delete-auth-cookie) may offer a work around, or two. Seems like a known issue.

Comment: @R.Richards Yeap, I chose the last answer in the post you shared and It got fixed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @R.Richards for sharing on older post. You can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122053/httpcontext-authentication-signoutasync-does-not-delete-auth-cookie)

I opted to use the following code in my Logout Action Method:

```
Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.<nameofcookie>");
```

In my **Startup.cs** and in **Configure** method:

```
 app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "ApplicationCookie",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true
        });

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "Facebook",
            AppId = "App_ID",
            AppSecret = "Secret_Id",
            SignInScheme = "ApplicationCookie",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true
        });
```

and in my **AccountController** in the **Logout** action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await _signinManager.SignOutAsync();
        Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.ApplicationCookie");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: is this still valid for AspNetCore 2.0. How is the name configured ".AspNetCore.ApplicationCookie", where is it "magically" set? Can we change that?

Comment: @YvesSchelpe I had to go back the project related to this post and upgrade it to AspNetCore 2.0 to be able to answer you. First of all, the set up is different now. [They have deprecated the previous setup](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1310)
As of the ".AspNetCore.ApplicationCookie" string, it's because in my setup in Startup.cs file I had:
`app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {AuthenticationScheme = "ApplicationCookie"});`
And I just prefixed it.Im not sure one can change .AspNetCore part but the rest of the key should be possible to change