# Cannot sign out the OpenIdConnect authentication of identityserver4 on ASP.NET Core 2 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

My Identity Server is using identityserver4 framework (http://localhost:9000). And I register the client on Identity Server as below.

```
clients.Add(
     new Client
     {
         ClientId = "customer.api",
         ClientName = "Customer services",
         AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials,
         RequireConsent = false,
         AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,

         RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:60001/signin-oidc" },
         PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:60001/signout-callback-oidc" },
         ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
         {
             new Secret("testsecret".Sha256())
         },
         AllowedScopes = new List<string>
         {
             IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
             IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
             IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
             IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
             "customerprivatelinesvn.api",                        
         },
         AllowOfflineAccess = true,
         AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
         AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:60001" }
     });
```

Here is the authentication on my client app (http://localhost:60001).

```
private void AddAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
{
    JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";       
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        Configuration.GetSection("OpenIdConnect").Bind(options);        
    });    
}    

"OpenIdConnect": {
    "SignInScheme": "Cookies",
    "Authority": "http://localhost:9000/",
    "RequireHttpsMetadata": false,
    "ClientId": "customer.api",
    "ClientSecret": "testsecret",
    "Scope": [ "customerprivatelinesvn.api", "offline_access" ],
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ResponseType": "code id_token token",
    "GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint": true,
    "SaveTokens": true
  }
```

**HomeController of client app**

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }    
}
```

Here are the Cookies of client app after user logs in.
[image]

I try to implement the signout action as below

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Signout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");                  
    }
}
```

But when user signs out, it doesn't call the endsession endpoint of identity server. I look at the traffic of fiddler, there is no request to identity server.

[image]

My expectation is when user signs out, it will call endsession endpoint of identity server and redirect to logout link of identity server as below.

[image]

[image]

We can do this easily on MVC application by calling OwinContext signout

```
private void LogoutOwin(IOwinContext context)
        {
            context.Authentication.SignOut();
        }
```

But the signout method doesn't work anymore on ASP.NET Core 2.

Note: I'm calling the signout action from an AJAX post because my client app is angular 5 app.

Does anyone know how to implement the signout correctly on ASP.NET Core 2?

Thank you very much.

Regards,

Kevin

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can resolve my problem now.

1) Return SignOutResult will call endsession endpoint.

2) Change AJAX post to submit form.

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Signout()
    {
        return new SignOutResult(new[] { "oidc", "Cookies" });            
    }
}


<form action="/Account/Signout" id="signoutForm" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('signoutForm').submit()">Sign out</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 27):

To allow the signing out to occur use the following Logout action:

```
public async Task Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
}
```

This is exactly what the quickstart says to use (http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html).
You (and I) have been too clever. I looked at the action in the tutorial and thought 'That's not complete, it doesn't return an action result, lets redirect back to my page'.

Actually what happens is `HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");` sets a default ActionResult (Which is to redirect to the OpenIdConnect provider to complete the sign-out). By specifying your own with `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");` you override this, so the sign-out action never happens.

### Redirect after logout

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48460580/509665), the way you specify a redirect URL after the logout is completed is by using AuthenticationProperties

```
public async Task Logout()
{
   await context.SignOutAsync("Cookies");
   var prop = new AuthenticationProperties
   {
       RedirectUri = "/logout-complete"
   };
   // after signout this will redirect to your provided target
   await context.SignOutAsync("oidc", prop);
}
```

Comment: Calling `controller.SignOut` produces a `SignOutResult` object that can then be returned from an `IActionResult` controller action. The `SignOutResult` class then calls `HttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync`. It's not a good idea to call `HttpContextExtensions.SignOutAsync` directly from within a controller action.

Answer (score 8):

On Net Core 2.0 change your code to use the enumerations CookieAuthenticationDefaults and OpenIdConnectDefaults

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddOpenIdConnect(SetOpenIdConnectOptions);


private static void SetOpenIdConnectOptions(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
{
    options.ClientId = "auAuthApp_implicit";
    options.Authority = "http://localhost:55379/";

    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ResponseType = "id_token token";
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

}
```

and...

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: I tried this (which appears to just change the display name of the authentication schemes) and still had the same problem

Answer (score 3):

.Net Core 3.1, using AuthenticationProperties to set the redirect url.

```
    public async Task Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Home/Logout-Complete" });
    }
```