# OpenIdConnect Authentication Cookie not being deleted on signing out

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, .net-6.0

I'm trying to implement OpenIdConnect as my authentication provider, using .NET6. I have the sign-in part working properly, however, on sign-out, the authentication cookie is not being deleted.

I've seen plenty of other threads referencing similar problems ([this, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489966/cannot-sign-out-the-openidconnect-authentication-of-identityserver4-on-asp-net-c) provides a pretty good summary of several of these), but none of the approaches seem to work.

Broadly speaking, my authentication code is configured as follows:

```
.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = AuthenticateScheme;
    options.DefaultSignOutScheme = AuthenticateScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = ChallengeScheme;
})
.AddCookie(AuthenticateScheme, options =>
{
    //trying to avoid having to add this!
    //options.Events.OnSigningOut = async ctx =>
    //{
    //    await Task.Run(() => ctx.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(CookieName));
    //};
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(ChallengeScheme, options =>
{
    options.SignInScheme = AuthenticateScheme;
    options.SignOutScheme = AuthenticateScheme;
    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.CallbackPath = CallbackPath;
    options.UsePkce = true;
    options.Authority = Authority;
    options.ClientId = ClientId;
    options.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;

    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add(OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId);
    options.Scope.Add(OpenIdConnectScope.OfflineAccess);
    options.Scope.Add(OpenIdConnectScope.Email);
    options.Scope.Add(OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile);
    options.MapInboundClaims = false;

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        RoleClaimType = "roles",
        NameClaimType = "preferred_username",
        ValidateIssuer = false
    };

    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = ctx =>
    {
        // Prevent redirect loop
        if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            ctx.HandleResponse();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };

    options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
    {
        context.HandleResponse();
        context.Response.BodyWriter.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(context.Exception.Message));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    };
});
```

And over on my Startup.cs, I have the following code within the `Configure` method:

```
app.Map("/Logout", map =>
{
    map.Run(async appBuilder =>
    {
        // tried this, didn't work
        //await appBuilder.SignOutAsync("MyAuthCookie", new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" });
        // tried this, didn't work
        //await appBuilder.SignOutAsync();
    });
});
app.UseNotFoundHandler();
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseGetaCategories();
app.UseGetaCategoriesFind();

app.UseAnonymousId();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "Default", pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapContent();
});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. For now, the only way I've been able to get this to work is to explicitly delete the cookie within the OnSigningOut event, but this doesn't feel like the right approach.

Comment: what is name of `authenticateScheme`?

Comment: Just an application-specific string - from what I'm aware, the actual name doesn't matter, does it? Or does the name bear some special significance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more complete logout should look something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Do the logout
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(AuthenticateScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(ChallengeScheme);

    //Important, this method should never return anything.
}
```

You might need to tweak the schema names if you don't use the default ones.

In the AddAuthentication method, I would se these settings, you want cookie for everything except the challenge.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = AuthenticateScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = ChallengeScheme;
})
```

Comment: But even if I were to sign out both cookies, the fact that currently it isn't removing the single one that I have means that trying both likely won't remove both, right? Or are you suggesting that the reason it's not removing the one currently, is because I'm not signing both out?

Comment: When you sigout, you don't signout a cookie("MyAuthCookie") ,  you signout from a Scheme name. And in a client you typically have the cookie and OpenIDConnect scheme to signout from.  Can you post the rest of your startup/program class?

Comment: Yeah apologies, the "MyAuthCookie" was me renaming it to obfuscate data. The value that exists there is the same one as the value that is set in the previous method where I say "options.SignInScheme = AuthenticateScheme". The entire code is pasted here - is there something in particular you'd like more information about?

Comment: updated my answer about AddAuthentication, does that help?

Comment: What does your request pipeline look like? The App.Use.... methods.

Comment: Going to try tweaking the cookies to match your suggestion. Regarding the App.Use stuff, I'll update my post to add them in.

Comment: updated my answer with your scheme name, try to replace your signout logic method with my action method instead, does that work?

Comment: Hi - apologies for taking so long. I ran a few tests, and for some reason, if I use CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, I just get an infinite loop when trying to sign in. Using the original code, with your suggested change of adding both SignOutAsync lines, correctly solves the original problem of the signout not working (thanks!), however, it introduces a new problem - when signing out, I'm simply redirected to the "stock" Microsoft signout page. I have my post_logout_redirect_uri configured "properly", and the path exists over on Azure, however it just goes to /logoutsession