# _signInManager.SignOutAsync() does not delete OAuth cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In Asp.net core application.I am trying using Azure AD account to sing out application using _signInManager.SignOutAsync() it logout will be working but browser cookies not clear.
In working scenario sign in application will be opened after sing out application.Again click the sing in it will automatically open the application in .net core.
I am trying to clear the cookies but oauth cookies not cleared.
How to clear cookies in .net core?

await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
but not working sign out option
Already tried this link:
[HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync does not delete auth cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122053/httpcontext-authentication-signoutasync-does-not-delete-auth-cookie)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LogoutAsync()
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(Actions.Index.ToString(), ControllersName.Home.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: How do you implement the AAD authentication ? By "Work or school accounts" template ? If yes ,try directly redirect user to "https://localhost:xxxxx/AzureAD/Account/SignedOut"