# AspNetCore 2.2 as API - How to logout using Identity methods?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I created web application with Angular 7 as [front-end](https://github.com/BiserB/NameGeneratorFrontend),
DotNetCore 2.2 as [back-end API](https://github.com/BiserB/NameGeneratorBackend) (SQL Server for db).
When I initially created the project, I didn't add Authentication, because
there is no need of UI pages. I plan to use Identity authentication with cookies.

While Login and [Authorize] work well, Logout doesn't work with signInManager.SignOutAsync().

Microsoft states:
"SignOutAsync clears the user's claims stored in a cookie.
 Don't redirect after calling SignOutAsync or the user will not be signed out."
Seems that the cookie is not deleted and it is accepted as valid from API (except when it is expired).
I tried with Response.Cookies.Delete() and HttpContext.SignOutAsync() without success.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("CORS", builder => 
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:42000")
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
        });
    });

    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<NGDbContext>(options =>  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<NGUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<NGDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // some options...
    });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        //options.CookieName = "MyCookie";
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    services.AddScoped<NamesService, NamesService>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        InitialSeeder.Seed(app);
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseCors("CORS");
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private UserManager<NGUser> userManager;
    private SignInManager<NGUser> signInManager;

    public AuthController(UserManager<NGUser> userManager, SignInManager<NGUser> signInManager)
    {
        this.userManager = userManager;
        this.signInManager = signInManager;
    }

    [HttpPost("Login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
    {
        var user = await this.userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Username);

        if (user == null)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        var signInResult = await this.signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, model.Password, false, false);

        if (!signInResult.Succeeded)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }

        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost("Logout")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Logout()
    {
        await this.signInManager.SignOutAsync();

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to benefit from Identity sign-in sign-out methods?
Or should use custom methods?

Comment: I found this similar question, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122053/httpcontext-authentication-signoutasync-does-not-delete-auth-cookie

Comment: I guess that APIs has no need of redirection at all.
So if signInManager.SignOutAsync() redirects it is not a proper method for API?

Comment: How do you know user has logined,do you use token?Maybe you could use IdentityServer4:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Answer (score 0):

For successful logout signInManager.SignOutAsync() just needs a cookie.
Which I didn't supply with Angular HttpClient.post() method - I missed null as second argument.
      Working Angular Side:

```
login(model: LoginModel){

    return this.http.post("https://localhost:50000/api/auth/login", model, { withCredentials: true });
  }

 logout(){

    return this.http.post("https://localhost:50000/api/auth/logout", null, { withCredentials: true });
  }
```

Working .Net Side:
Both logout approaches work:

- this.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Identity.Application");
- await this.signInManager.SignOutAsync();

The first deletes only selected cookie, while the second deletes three `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application`, `Identity.External` ,`Identity.TwoFactorUserId`.
SignOutAsync calls three methods:
`await Context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);`
`await Context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);`
`await Context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme);`

Yes, it is possible to use Identity in API.