# Prevent user to access the application with cookie after sign out

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

In my .net core 3.1 App there is a Scenario when login with user then take cookies from local storage after that logged out. then try to access API with this cookie using postman it can access the API normally I want to prevent this

in startup

`options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents { OnValidatePrincipal = SecurityStampValidator.ValidatePrincipalAsync };`

when signout

var authenticationName = HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name;

```
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(authenticationName);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
                await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
            }

            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync does not delete auth cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122053/httpcontext-authentication-signoutasync-does-not-delete-auth-cookie)

Comment: No it didn't I can delete cookie but if I take it before logout I can access the end points by these cookies I want to prevent this.