How do I show a Windows login prompt on every visit to a Razor page in an ASP.NET Core application?
I am attempting to have the browser prompt the user for their Windows login credentials on each visit to a page I have setup.  The reason for this, is that our customer is wanting the user to have to enter their credentials after each successful logout.
The users will access the site on their own internal network, and the application will be using Windows authentication.
I have the app configured to service IIS in the Startup:
if (useWindowsAuth)
{
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(iis =>
    {
        iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
        iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
    });
}

The login page model is decorated with an Authorize attribute:
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class WindowsModel : PageModel

In IIS, both Anonymous Authentication and Windows Authentication are enabled.
When the page loads, I correctly get the prompt to enter the user's credentials.
When the user clicks to logout, I provide a button for them to return to login. At this point, the credentials should show again.
However, after logging in, then revisiting the login page, the prompt is skipped.
If I delete the browser cache, cookies, and history, and then re-load the page, I do get the prompt again.  So it seems the browser is keeping the authentication.
How do I go about un-authenticating the user programmatically OR how do I get the cache, cookies, etc. cleared out programmatically from the browser so the prompt shows every time the user visits the login page?
Or is there a better way to get this prompt to show each time the page is loaded?
Thanks in advance!
Things I tried:
I tried to send an Unauthorized() response from the page's OnGet method, which works the first visit, but each successive visit to the page, the prompt is skipped.
Update:
The logout workflow is tied to our identity provider (Identity Server) which executes the following code to clean up any local cookies and then redirects the user back to the client:
var context = await _interaction.GetLogoutContextAsync(logoutId);

if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true)
{
    // delete local authentication cookie
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    
}

if (context != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.PostLogoutRedirectUri))
{
    return Redirect(context.PostLogoutRedirectUri);
}

return Page();   


"both Anonymous Authentication" why? Why not just Windows Authentication? "When the user clicks to logout, I provide a button for them to return to login" what does that button do, does it clear the session cache? HttpContext.Session.Clear() maybe?

@Charlieface, thank you for your reply.  I added the context/code for the logout workflow above.  As for the anonymous authentication, we have some pages that don't require authentication/authorization so we allow anonymous.

Looks like this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/48460580/14868997

@Charlieface - thank you for the link.  I do see some code in there that I did not think of.  I will add that into the logout workflow and report back results.
